# Dropdown menu not working on heroku after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple drop down menu which works great locally but when I deploy my application to Heroku, it doesn't work. It doesn't show menu options. So, when I click on Account, nothing happens.

I have added this in my production.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Tired this before pushing code to Heroku, But still it not working for me

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "compiled assets"
git push heroku master
```

Here is my code:

```
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle count-info" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                  My Account &nbsp; <i class="caret"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-settings">
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to user_path(current_user) do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp; Profile
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to edit_user_path(current_user) do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &nbsp; Edit Profile
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to edit_user_registration_path do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> &nbsp; Change Password
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
                    <% end %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li> 
              <li>
                <div class="m-t-sm">
                  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'fa fa-sign-out'%>
                </div>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li>
                <div class="m-t-sm">
                  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path, :class => 'btn btn-link btn-md'%> or
                  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'btn btn-md btn-success btn-rounded m-l'%>
                </div>
              </li>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: please check if there are any js errors in the browser console?

Comment: It says:  Uncaught Error: rails-ujs has already been loaded!

Comment: @DikshaDhakate You don't need to precompile assets and commit on heroku. It will automatically precompile your assets. please don't precompile in local and pu sh it on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by removing this code from application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>
```